# Do 1MHz 3.3V through-hole oscillators exist?

Tags: oscillator, components, hobbyist

I'm beginning my first MCU project and I'm having trouble finding a suitable oscillator. I want to run an ATtiny261 at very low power. It will be lighting up different combinations of LEDs based on look-up tables, indexed by analog sensor ranges. The data sheet advises using an external oscillator when using the ADC.

Since I'm prototyping this on a breadboard and generally don't have a lot of experience with soldering small parts I've been trying to find all through-hole components. I'm having a lot of trouble finding any through-hole oscillators that are sub-2MHz and 3.3V:

- [At Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/c/passive-components/frequency-control-timing-devices/?termination%20style=Through%20Hole) as soon as I select through-hole the options start at 3MHz (with the exception of a 455KHz option, which seems incompatible with the specs in [the ATtiny261 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2588-8-bit-avr-microcontrollers-tinyavr-attiny261-attiny461-attiny861_datasheet.pdf)).
- On the other hand, [if I select 1MHz, 3.3V oscillators](https://www.mouser.com/c/passive-components/frequency-control-timing-devices/oscillators/standard-clock-oscillators/?frequency=1%20MHz&operating%20supply%20voltage=1.8%20V%2C%202.5%20V%2C%203.3%20V%7C%7E3.3%20V&product%20type=Clock%20Oscillators%7C%7EOCXO%20Oscillators%7C%7ETCXO%20Oscillators&instock=y) the options are limited to SMD components.

Is there a fundamental electrical reason I'm having trouble finding these parts or is the industry just moving away from through hole parts so completely that these parts simply aren't made anymore?

If these parts simply don't exist, is my best option to use [a plain crystal component](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ECS/ECS-10-13-1X?qs=aGohqJksTCIrTsluVTAbvQ%3D%3D) and build my own oscillator circuit based on [a tutorial like this one?](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/crystal.html)

Comment: Do you want an oscillator, or do you want a crystal that can be used to tune the oscillator circuit on the ATtiny chip?

Comment: An external oscillator will take a lot of power. It is not compatible with your plan.

Comment: What's wrong with the oscillator on the MCU? Lighting up LEDs is hardly timing sensitive, and it doesn't sound like you need good accuracy from the ADC either.

Comment: The old [HA7210](https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/intersil_fn3389.pdf) works from 2-7 V and from 10 kHz to 10 MHz. It's specifically designed for low power applications. I've used them. Still have some. But what is your specification current (and at what frequency?) Also, you might consider other MCUs if very very low power is desired and if the functional specs allow it.

Comment: I would be very interested to see where exactly in the documentation it recommends an external oscillator when using the ADC. Just to be sure that you are not chasing ghosts here.

Comment: @Justme it doesn't say that directly but at the bottom of p150 it says ADC noise reduction is more important above 1MHz. The internal clocks are 128kHz and 8Mhz. The first seems too slow and the second seems too high. Maybe I'm either misunderstanding or maybe I'm assuming I need more accurate measurements than I do?

Comment: @ThePhoton it seems like that would work, assuming you're talking about the setup described in section 6.2.6 on p30? http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2588-8-bit-avr-microcontrollers-tinyavr-attiny261-attiny461-attiny861_datasheet.pdf

Comment: If the purpose of reading the ADCs is to determine which lights light up, there's no point in doing it at 1 MHz or worrying about a small amount of noise. Check the ADC at (at most) 10 Hz and put the uC to sleep for 99 ms out of every 100. But also realize that trying to drop the uC power below 1 mW is pretty pointless when your LEDs will likely consume at least 20 mW each.

Comment: The note on p 150 says you need to use noise reduction mode when running the ADC above 1 MHz. That implies that noise is **not** a problem when running the ADC slower. The human eye can only follow changes in light intensity at about 20 Hz maximum (this is how television and movies work) so even 128 kHz is plenty to keep the eye fooled into thinking the lights are changing continuously. Probably 32 kHz would be plenty, and allow using the lowest power oscillator---but again there's little point in lowering the uC power below 1% of your lamp power.

Comment: @ThePhoton It sounds like I've misunderstood a few details. Initially I the internal clock was 8 MHz and that was the clock referenced in that p150 note. From the other feedback here it sounds like I can scale that down and the p150 note is referencing that scaled down clock. It sounds like you're saying that the system clock really only matters if I'm trying to continuously sample the ADC. Is that right?

My goal here is to use the ADC to read 6 hall effect sensors to determine the rotation of 3 cubes and light up the LEDs (rarely) only when valid combinations are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to run an ATtiny261 at **very low power**...I'm having a lot of
> trouble finding any through-hole oscillators that are sub-2MHz and
> 3.3V:

Crystal oscillator modules tend to draw quite high current (typically 10-30 mA) which is incompatible with very low power operation. They may be OK for breadboard prototyping, but you probably don't want to use one in the final product.

> or is the industry just moving away from through hole parts so
> completely that **these parts simply aren't made anymore**?

Yes. What's worse is a lot of newer ICs are only available in lead-less packages like BGA and WSON that can't be soldered by hand at all. This is no problem for the industry because hand soldering is avoided as much as possible to keep costs down etc., but is annoying for prototyping and hobbyist use. This has lead to the rise of pre-populated 'breakout boards' for specialized smd parts that cannot easily be hand soldered.

> is my best option to use a plain crystal component and **build my own**
> **oscillator circuit** based on a tutorial like this one?

You could do that (I recommend the 'CMOS Crystal Oscillator') but your best option might be to use a 'plain crystal' with the ATtiny's own crystal oscillator circuit. This will be easier to build and use fewer components, and may have lower current draw. The only downside is that it uses up another I/O pin.

Answer (score 1):

The fact of the matter is that CMOS with lower power and faster rise time has lower impedance and lower capacitance and this becomes critically sensitive to long leads of DIPs without a ground plane due to the parasitic inductance around 8 nH/cm. (that includes 10:1 probe ground clip lengths).

It is also cheaper to produce and has a higher demand, so cost is beneficial.  **So the faster you learn how to SMT solder on PCB's the better your experience will be.**  Youtube has many videos on DIY how to SMT solder with ovens, hot plates and hot air guns.

There are several low-cost prototype shops that make PCBs for entry-level users.  No need to design, just copy.

examples of low-cost Crystal Oscillators in SMT.

https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/294/NJU6368series_E-2302671.pdf

If you can't design it yet , buy it and learn how to add resistor wire test points/pins for sig & gnd, so you can use the 10:1 probe without clip and gnd wire just using tip & ring for textbook waveforms rather than false waveforms from coaxial cable capacitance + gnd wire inductance resonance ringing.

This learning curve includes using twisted pairs for interface wiring, in order to lower the impedance to be closer to matching the low CMOS driver impedance and reduce crosstalk and EMI issues.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, such oscillators likely exist, but that is not important, you don't need an oscillator.

You have understood the datasheet wrong. The data sheet does not advice using an external oscillator when using the ADC.

What the data sheet advices, is that when you require high accuracy, the ADC noise reduction mode should be used, especially if the system frequency is above 1 MHz.

First question is, do you even require high accuracy, and even if you do, then just use the noise canceler mode if you use higher than 1 MHz clock.

If you really do want to use 1 MHz system clock, you can just use the internal 8 MHz oscillator and set the clock prescaler to 8 to get the system clock down to 1 MHz if you are that worried about noise or don't want to use ADC noise canceler for some reason.

In practice, many other sources of noise could affect the readings far more than using 8MHz clock, such as sensor output impedance.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! When I read table 19-1 it shows examples of the relationship between the clock, voltage, and the current. Footnote 7 says _"Values are with external clock ..."_. If I use the internal oscillator with the prescaler as you suggest, should I expect the current relationship to follow the 8MHz line of that table, 1MHz line, or would that table not apply at all?

Comment: That's a whole new question then. And external clock will consume different amount of current. I assume 8 MHz clock source is not divided so system clock is 8 MHz too.